# How to convert ObjectHandle from Pkcs11Interop to X509 Certificate or Pem format?

Tags: c#, pkcs11interop

How to convert Public key from Pkcs11Interop to X509 certificate or pem format

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve in more details? Maybe add some code. Currently its very hard to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks jariq.   I want to send public key to another program that support only pem format or X509 format.  for my code // Generate asymetric key pair
                    ObjectHandle publicKey = null;
                    ObjectHandle privateKey = null;
                    List<ObjectAttribute> publicKeyAttributes = null;
                    List<ObjectAttribute> privateKeyAttributes = null;
                    GenerateKeyPair(session,out publicKeyAttributes, out privateKeyAttributes,out publicKey, out privateKey);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract RSA public key value then you need to read `CKA_PUBLIC_EXPONENT` and `CKA_MODULUS` attributes.